# LTC4412 for Alternate Power

Tags: power-supply, power, usb, switching

[image]

I want to use LTC4412 in my PCB as power switch. My Primary Power is 12-24V from Adopter and Auxilary Power is 5V from USB. In normal condition when Auxilary power is detected then system will disconnect Primary power from Load. But that's not my concern. My issue is if primary power is not available at load and then if i connect Auxilary power(USB) then will system detect the USB and power will be supplied to the system Via USB or Primary power has to be connected all the time before switching to auxilary power?

Answer (score 0):

The STAT pin is open drain so it's probably safe to assume that it will be high impedance if the chip is unpowered (no battery). You will still have conduction through the wall adapter input MOSFET's body diode so the load will be powered but you may need to use a larger MOSFET since there will be more power dissipation than if it were turned on.